# Angular Checkboxes in mat-table initial value

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a mat-table of rules, which can be activated with a checkbox. I dont know how to implement an inital value for the checkbox. This is, how it looks like at the moment.

```
    <ng-container  matColumnDef="activate">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="text-center">activate</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = dataIndex;" class="text-center">
            <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.checked" (change)="saveActivation(element, i, $event.checked)"></mat-checkbox>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
```

I reached to use the saveActivation-Method to save the "checked"-value and put it in my database. That works. Now i want, that all checkboxes will be "checked" after the app started, when the specific object of my rules has a "true" boolean value, so it "remember", that the rule is active.

```
export interface Rule {
  rule: string;
  points: string;
  description: string;
  activated: boolean;
}

a saved rule-object:
{
    "activated": true,
    "description": "goalDifference is right",
    "points": 3,
    "rule": "rightDifference"
}
```

Any ideas, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To set the check-box from rule object value which is showing true and false  you can use material by default directive [checked]="true || false",

here I have done some implementation basis on the response from the API

<mat-checkbox [checked]="true||false" color="primary" class="example-margin">

Comment: The thing is, even simple default like "[checked]="true" " doesnt work, the checkbox is empty. And i want, that the default value based on the "activated"-values of my dataSource.

Comment: In your dataSource the key value already comes with true and false right so i just gave you an overview how you can give the value to checkbox. now bind the value based on the dataSource key value like this 
<mat-checkbox [checked]="element.activated" color="primary" class="example-margin">
the check box will get value based on your datasource value.

Comment: yea, but how i told - this doesnt work. Normally the box should be checked, if i try the easiest form - [checked]="true". But the box is not checked. I tried it with my array, where all my rules are saved, like - [checked]="allRules[i].activated" - but this doesnt work too